# React proptypes warning before component is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-proptypes

I have a component that wraps around other components and conditionally renders them when all their necessary data has loaded. However, I'm getting proptype errors -- along the lines of `the prop x is marked as required in component Y but its value is undefined`. `prop x` is data that hasn't returned from the server yet, and `component Y` is the child component that will render when the data comes back.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<Wrapper contentLoaded={hasDataLoaded && !!dataThatWillLoad}>
  <ComponentWithData
    dataThatWillLoad={dataThatWillLoad}
    dataThatAlreadyExists={dataThatAlreadyExists}
   />
</Wrapper>
```

and my wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper = ({ contentLoaded, children }) => {
  if (contentLoaded) return children;
  return <p>Loading</p>;
}
```

This would give the error `Prop dataThatWillLoad is marked as required in component ComponentWithData but its value is undefined`.

This seems strange to me, since the `ComponentWithData` isn't even being rendered until the data comes back. Does this have something to do with when the proptypes are checked? This particular piece of data is coming into the component via a mapStateToProps, could that have something to do with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it written, the children will always be created, leading to your problem. By adding them as children, unconditionally, to your wrapper component, React will make them before adding them to the children prop. Another way of doing this would be to add a prop to your wrapper with the component itself. You can see an example of this in the `Route` component provided by the React Router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

Using this design pattern, you should be able to skip the rendering by only rendering the component when props are loaded and loading a separate component when they are not.

Edit: TLDR: the way you have it set up, the `ComponentWithData` component is created and given props before being given as a child to your wrapper.

Comment: Oh, that's actually really cool. I wasn't aware that components had any kind of existence that would affect the proptypes outside of when the component lifecycle kicks off. The more you know. Thanks!